# Maven Producing Empty JAR

Tags: java, maven-2, jar

I have the following pom file:

```
<build>
    <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
    <sourceDirectory>src/web</sourceDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>src/web/**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My source files are in the src/web/org/myCompany/ folder. When I run the pom file, I get a JAR generated with no class files. What is wrong with the way that I specified the source directories? I do not get any error messages, just an empty JAR (with some META-INF files).

On a sidenote, why does maven have both the `<sourceDirectory>` tag and the `<include>` tag on the maven compiler plugin? They seem to be redundant (except that the include tag allows multiple source directories).

Comment: You dont need to set sourceDirectory and include on the maven-compiler-plugin? Your soure files should be under src/main/java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying this with the latest version of `maven compiler plugin`, which is `2.3.2` after removing the `<includes>` `<configuration>` section as indicated by others?

In any case, I think `<includes>` would be a filter within the `<sourceDirectory>` and thus cannot have `src/web` specified again.

Comment: I changed the compiler version to 2.3.2. The problem persisted. Then, I removed the includes and configuration under the compiler-plugin and got an error about the configuration being mandatory. I then removed the entire maven-compiler-plugin entry from my pom file and the build started to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves you don't need the includes. The sourceDirectory specification should be enough. Then run

```
 mvn clean package
```

Comment: Would I need something like <sourceDirectory>src/web/org/myCompany? Or maybe src/web/org/myCompany/**?

Comment: Can you have look in your target directory? Are there any .class files?

Comment: Target\classes directory is empty